# extract multiple values from string based on REGEXP_INSTR in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

HI have following  sample string.

'Claim Number: 299765Member: JOHNSON,XYZ  Service Line Number 1
    Action Code 0    Response Directive 1641800532    Advice Line 2 Service Line
    Number 2    Action Code 0    Response Directive 400    Procedure Code
    4805587'

I need to extract the values after Response Directive string  when ever there is a Response Directive String identified in the whole string .

```
WITH TEST AS(
SELECT 'Claim Number: 299765Member: JOHNSON,XYZ  Service Line Number 1                
Action Code 0    Response Directive 1641800532    Advice Line 2 Service Line         
Number 2    Action Code 0    Response Directive 400    Procedure Code   
4805587'
AS NOTE_TEXT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT,'response directive+\s+(\w+)',1,1,'i',1) as       
NUM_VAL
FROM TEST;
```

Right now I am resulted with only one result based on above query I written

**NUM_VAL**

1641800532

Expected Result Set

**NUM_VAL**

1641800532

400

Kindly help for multiple Occurrences. Thank You

Comment: I changed "FROM dual;" to "FROM TEST;" in the last line of your code (the outer query does not select from dual) and removed the sqldeveloper tag as it has nothing to do with your problem. Question: why the + at the end of `directive` in your regexp? That simply allows for one or more occurrences of the letter `e` at the end of the word `directive`. If you didn't mean that, you can edit your post yourself and delete that +. Didn't want to do it for you without asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways.

## A) Decide on a maximum number of possible occurrences to support

In this approach, duplicate the input data say, 50 times, and search the 1st duplicate for the 1st occurrence, the 2nd duplicate for the 2nd occurrence, etc.

Any occurrence that doesn't exist in the input data will be `null`, so you will need to filter those out in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH TEST AS(
SELECT 'Claim Number: 299765Member: JOHNSON,XYZ  Service Line Number 1                
Action Code 0    Response Directive 1641800532    Advice Line 2 Service Line         
Number 2    Action Code 0    Response Directive 400    Procedure Code   
4805587'
AS NOTE_TEXT FROM DUAL
),
occurrences AS ( SELECT rownum occurrence# FROM dual connect by -- Max 50 occurrences supported
rownum <= 50 )  
SELECT regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT,'response directive+\s+(\w+)',1,occurrences.occurrence#,'i',1) as       
NUM_VAL
FROM test cross join occurrences
WHERE regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT,'response directive+\s+(\w+)',1,occurrences.occurrence#,'i',1) IS NOT NULL;
```

## B) Use a `LATERAL` inline view (only works in Oracle 12c or later)

This version will support any number of occurrences and should perform better since you are not duplicating the data 50 times to only find one or two occurrences.  Unfortunately, it does not work in 11g, which you said you are on.  I'm including it only for completeness.

```
-- 12c version
WITH TEST AS(
SELECT 'Claim Number: 299765Member: JOHNSON,XYZ  Service Line Number 1                
Action Code 0    Response Directive 1641800532    Advice Line 2 Service Line         
Number 2    Action Code 0    Response Directive 400    Procedure Code   
4805587'
AS NOTE_TEXT FROM DUAL
)
SELECT regexp_substr(NOTE_TEXT,'response directive+\s+(\w+)',1,occurrences.occurrence#,'i',1) as       
NUM_VAL
FROM test cross join lateral ( SELECT rownum occurrence# FROM dual connect by -- Max 50 occurrences supported
rownum <= regexp_count(note_text, 'response directive+\s+(\w+)',1,'i') ) occurrences
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a standard `connect by level` query:

```
with 
     test (note_text) as (
       select 'Claim Number: 299765Member: JOHNSON,XYZ  Service Line Number 1
               Action Code 0    Response Directive 1641800532    Advice Line 2 Service Line
               Number 2    Action Code 0    Response Directive 400    Procedure Code   
               4805587'
       from    dual
     )
select  level as lvl,
        regexp_substr(note_text,'response directive (\d+)', 1, level, 'i', 1) as num_val
from    test
connect by level <= regexp_count(note_text, 'response directive \d+', 1, 'i')
order by lvl;
```

**Output**:

```
  LVL NUM_VAL
----- ----------
    1 1641800532
    2 400

2 rows selected.
```

This will only catch NUMBERS following "response directive". You may change back to `\w+` (instead of `\d+`) if you really meant that. It also allows for exactly one space after "responsive directive" - you may change back to `\s+` if you prefer.

Comment: This answers the question, but you're assuming there is only ever one row in `test`.